# Python TelegramBot SQLITE3 Обновление баланса в БД

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot, telebot

Всем привет!
Столкнулся с проблемой при попытке создать изменения в балансе для телеграмм бота
Использую TelegramBotAPI (Он же telebot) и Sqlite3

```
user = message.from_user.id
sql = "UPDATE main SET balance = ? \
                 WHERE user_id = ?"
val = ("balance + 15", user)
c.execute(sql, val)
conn.commit()
```

При работе в balance он просто записывает значение "balance + 15"

Пробовал делать "небезопасным" методом:

```
c.execute("UPDATE main SET balance = balance + 15 \
                       WHERE user_id = id_пользователя ")
conn.commit()
```

В этом случае баланс записывается правильно, но работает только если руками указать id конкретного пользователя

Помогите. люди добрые

Answer (score 2):

`balance` записывается как строка, а не переменная, попробуйте поменять переменную `val` на
`val = (f'{int(balance)} + 15', user)`